# How to refresh ListView row after delete row from BaseExpandableListAdapter?

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview

In my app i'm using BaseExpandableListAdapter to show my database. i created a button in the "getChildView" and when i click it the current row is deleted. my problem is that the listView updating on the MainActivity.class and not at BaseExpandableListAdapter.class . how can i refresh the data after was changed in a different class and refreshing in real time.

MainActivity.class i get the data from Db in ArrayList:

```
hand = new DbHandler(getActivity());
        fullList = new HashMap<ArrayList<ClockModel>, ArrayList<ClockModel>>();
        ArrayList<ClockModel> temp = new ArrayList<ClockModel>();

        child = new ArrayList<ClockModel>();
        child = hand.getDay(workName);

        for (int i = 0; i < child.size(); i++) {

            ClockModel m1 = new ClockModel(
                    child.get(i).getId(),
                    child.get(i).getWorkName(),
                    child.get(i).getDateDay(), 
                    child.get(i).getDateMonth(),
                    child.get(i).getDateYear()
                    temp.add(m1);       
                    fullList.put(child, child);
        }
```

and on BaseExpandableListAdapter i have a button that delete the spacific row:

```
btnRemove = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_btnRemove);
        btnRemove.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DbHandler hand = new DbHandler(context);
                int currendId = fullList.get(child).get(groupPosition).getId();
                hand.deleteDay(currendId);
                Toast.makeText(context, "Del : "+currendId, 2000).show();       

            }
        });
```

Thank you..:)

Answer (score 1):

After deleting row notify adapter using

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: But i set the adapter in external class(MainActivity).. lv.setAdapter(adapter)

Comment: you can simply call notifyDataSetChanged(); inside the adapter getview